# nginx try_files absolute path

Tags: nginx

I'm new at nginx, what I'd like to do is catch all image requests (*.jpg|png|gif) and forward them to a php script outside the scope of root.

My current, kinda working script is this:

```
server {

   index index.php;

   # PHP-FPM
   location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   }

   # Images handler
   root /var/www/images-handler;
   location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png) {
      rewrite ^ /img.php last;
   }

}
```

The problem is that I have to change the `root` variable to `/var/www/website-contents`. Since `website-contents` and `images-handler` don't have the same parent directory, I add a `root` variable to my `location` segment like so:

```
root /var/www/website-contents;

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png) {
   root /var/www/images-handler;
   rewrite ^ /img.php last;
}
```

But it doesn't work. All the images return a 404 response.

Do I *have* to make `/var/www` the root, and add `website-contents` and `images-handler` in their own `location` segments, `/` and `~* \.(gif|jpg|png)` respectively? Should I make a symbolic link for `/var/www/images-handler` inside `/var/www/website-contents`?

Is there a better solution to all of this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, all php scripts are executed by your `location ~ \.php$` block, with the `root` you provided. If you want to execute a php script with a different root, you need to override that location. There are a number of ways to achieve this. Just for one php script, a `location =` would be simplest. For example:

```
root /var/www/website-contents;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png) {
    rewrite ^ /img.php last;
}

location = /img.php {
    root /var/www/images-handler;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It works, and I finally understand what's really going on. I've spent hours trying to figure it out, thank you!